# How to delay one of two signals but discard it if necessary?

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism, system.reactive, reactiveui

I use ReactiveUI and Prism in my Xamarin.Forms application.

Prism, on one side controls the page appear/disappear signal and sends the disappear event just before the view-navigation animation starts.
ReactiveUI on the other side offers a `view.WhenActivated(...)` extension to only establish view-bindings when the view is shown. The `view.WhenActivated()` gets disposed when the disappear event is fired.

Since Prism is sending the disappear event while the view-to-unload is still shown, the view bindings gets dissolved in front of the customers eyes.

To prevent this I tried to register my own copy of ReactiveUI's implementation of `IActivationForViewFetcher` (`ReactiveUI.XamForms.ActivationForViewFetcher`) and delay the disappear event just as long as the animation isn't over yet (1 second).

```cs
var appearing = Observable.FromEvent<EventHandler, bool>(
       eventHandler =>
       {
         void handler(object sender, EventArgs e) => eventHandler(true);

         return handler;
       },
       x => page.Appearing += x,
       x => page.Appearing -= x)
     // timestamp the event for later take-last scan
    .Timestamp();

var disappearing = Observable.FromEvent<EventHandler, bool>(
       eventHandler =>
        {
          void handler(object sender, EventArgs e) => eventHandler(false);

          return handler;
        },
       x => page.Disappearing += x,
       x => page.Disappearing -= x)
     // timestamp the event for later take-last scan
    .Timestamp()
     // slow-down the disappearing event to avoid visual un-binding effects
     // like re-enabled buttons, values unset and so on.
    .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
    .ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler);

return Observable
    .Merge(appearing, disappearing)
    .Scan(new Timestamped<bool>(false, DateTimeOffset.MinValue),
       (last, n) => n.Timestamp >= last.Timestamp ? n : last)
    .Select(v => v.Value)
    .DistinctUntilChanged();
```

This works well in case the user is slow but for some scenarios the disappear-delay may render the active page as deactivated.

Now to my question:

Is there a easier way to delay the disappear signal but avoid it as a whole just in case the page was re-activated in the delay-window?

A bit more information: the appear and disappear events may be triggered by the frameworks more than once so that a de/activated page may be de/activated again without effect.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you use _two_ mvvm-frameworks simultaneously?

Comment: It's pretty common to have both used. RxUi is designed to be agnostic.

Comment: I use ReactiveUI for the reactive base types and reactive-support, Prism for the comfortable navigation and DI support. They have some overlap but play nice together.